# Can I send strings to New Relic?

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I want to send metrics to New Relic with string as the value, but I can't find any docs on how to do that. Are metrics limited to numerical values by New Relic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All reported metrics are required to be numerical. In some places the metric name will be exposed but it will always be tied to a numerical value.

https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/how-new-relic-works-with-plugin-data#metric_values